# Stirling number Combinatorics. Summation .

Tags: combinatorics, summation, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ {n\atop k} \right\} *(x)_k  = x^n $$  is well known .

What if the k-th term of LHS summation is divided by $q^k$ where $q$ is some positive constant,
What about 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n[ \left\{ {n\atop k} \right\} *(x)_k ]/(q^k) =  ? $$

Comment: Good one. Good one.

Comment: would be great if you coulld share this to the best minds here :)

Comment: This isn't a complete solution, but here's a quick combinatorial interpretation: for any given $k$, $\left\{ {n\atop k} \right\} \cdot (x)_k = \left\{ {n\atop k} \right\}k! \binom{x}{k}$ which is the number of ways to choose a $k$-element subset of $[x]$ and choose a surjective function from $[n]$ onto that subset.  Thus, $\left\{ {n\atop k} \right\} \cdot (x)_k $ is the number of functions from $[n] \to [x]$ whose image has cardinality $k$.  Now, define $y = q^{-1}$ to be a formal variable.

Comment: Then multiplying by $y^k$ is the equivalent of choosing a function from the image of our previous function to $[y]$.  If you can prove that this is equal to something else (combinatorially), then you can formally plug in $y  = q^{-1}$ at the end (everything is finite, so these are all polynomials, so there are no problems there) to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I think your interpretations are beneficial but the main key here is the problem you defined in the end.

Comment: Nice to see that someone's actually working on it!